# PHP FTP Upload BLOB TEMP Image

Tags: javascript, php, ftp, blob, temporary-files

I am trying to upload an Image of a Form via FTP.
But because I validate my Form with Javascript I can't offer PHP the File Object.
Instead I pass the temporary blob path of the image.
When I try to upload, it doesn't work.
If I take then the blob path and put it manually in the brwoser line it displayes the image which means my blob path isn't corrupt.
Can't PHP / FTP take an blob temp image as the source file?
Here is my Code:

### Javascript and HTML

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#testImageSelect').change( function(event) {
  var validation = false;
  var message = "";
  validation = validateImage();
  if(validation){
   message = "Javascript: Das Bild ist ok!";
   $("#submitTest").attr("disabled",false);
  }else{
   message = "Javascript: Das Bild entspricht nicht den Anforderungen!";
   $("#submitTest").attr("disabled",true);
  }
  document.getElementById("scriptresultJs").innerHTML = "<p>"+message+"</p>";
 });
 
 $("#submitTest").click(function () {
  var message = "";
  var dataSubmit = [];
  var pic = document.getElementById("testImageSelect").files[0];
  var pic_path = URL.createObjectURL(pic);
  var picture = [];
  picture = {
   tmp_path: pic_path,
   name: pic.name,
   size: pic.size
  }
  dataSubmit = {
   castingcity: "Coruscant",
   forename: "Anakin",
   lastname: "Skywalker",
   geschlecht: "Männlich"
  };
  var result = "default";
  result = $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      async: false,   // WICHTIG! 
      url: 'http://hiddentalents.de/php/test.php',
      data: ({
       data: dataSubmit,
       picture: picture
         })
  }).responseText;
  message = result;
  document.getElementById("scriptresultPHP").innerHTML = "<p>"+message+"</p>";
 });
});

function validateImage() {
 var validation = false;
 var pic = $("#testImageSelect").val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
 var ext = pic.substring(pic.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
 if(ext == "JPEG" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "JPG"){
  validation = true;
 } 
 else{
  validation = false;
 }
 return validation;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Servertesting</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <form role="form" method="post" action="" id="testForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" id="testImageSelect" name="testImageSelect" required>
  </form>
  <button class="btn btn-default" id="submitTest" disabled>Abschicken</button>
  <div id="scriptresultJs"></div>
  <p id="scriptresultPHP"></p>
 </body>

</html>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
$db_host = "rdbms.strato.de";
$db_datenbank = "(name of database)"; 
$db_username = "(username)"; 
$db_password = "(password)";

$output = "";

SESSION_START();

# Datenbankverbindung herstellen 
$datenbank = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_datenbank);

# Hat die Verbindung geklappt ? 
if ($datenbank->connect_errno) {
    $output = $output . "\n" . "Fehler beim Verbinden mit der Datenbank: (" . $datenbank->connect_errno . ") " . $datenbank->connect_error;
}
//UTF 8 einstellen
mysqli_query($datenbank, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");

# Wurde überhaupt was eingetragen?
if(isset($_POST["data"])) {
    //Image überprüfung:
    $output = $output . "\n". $_POST["picture"]["tmp_path"];
    $target_dir = "temp/";
    $target_file_path = $target_dir . date('dmYHis_') . $_POST["picture"]["name"];
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file_path,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file_path)) {
        $output = $output . "\n" . "Es tut uns leid, das gewählte Bild existiert bereits.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_POST["picture"]["size"] > 1500000) {
        $output = $output . "\n" . "Die Bilddatei ist leider zu groß.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "JPG" && $imageFileType != "JPEG" ) {
        $output = $output . "\n" . "Leider sind nur JPG bzw. JPEG Dateien erlaubt. Sie haben eine " . $imageFileType . " Datei hochgeladen!";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        $output = "Die Datei konnte leider nicht hochgeladen werden. Folgende Fehler sind verantwortlich:\n".$output;
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        //Upload Image
        $ftp_server = "ftp.strato.de";
        $ftp_user_name = "(username)";
        $ftp_user_pass = "(password)";
        $destination_file = $target_file_path;
        $source_file = $_POST['picture']["temp_path"];

        // Verbindung aufbauen
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

        // Login mit Benutzername und Passwort
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

        // Verbindung überprüfen
        if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
            $output = $output . "\n" . "FTP-Verbindung ist fehlgeschlagen!";
            $output = $output . "\n" . "Verbindungsaufbau zu $ftp_server mit Benutzername $ftp_user_name versucht.";
            exit;
        } else {
            $output = $output . "\n" . "Verbunden zu $ftp_server mit Benutzername $ftp_user_name";
        }

        // Datei hochladen
        $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY);

        // Upload überprüfen
        if (!$upload) {
            $output = $output . "\n" . "FTP-Upload ist fehlgeschlagen!\nDie Datei $source_file konnte nicht auf dem Server $ftp_server als $destination_file hochgeladen werden!";
        } else {
            $output = $output . "\n" . "Datei $source_file auf Server $ftp_server als $destination_file hochgeladen";
        }

        // Verbindung schließen
        ftp_close($conn_id);

        //Datenbankeinträge machen:
        $castingcity = mysqli_real_escape_string($datenbank,$_POST["data"]["castingcity"]);
        $forename = mysqli_real_escape_string($datenbank,$_POST["data"]["forename"]);
        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($datenbank,$_POST["data"]["lastname"]);
        $geschlecht = mysqli_real_escape_string($datenbank,$_POST["data"]["geschlecht"]);
        $picture = $target_file_path;
        //Insert Data (except Image)
        $sql = "INSERT INTO candidates_temp (castingcity, forename, lastname, geschlecht, picture)
        VALUES ('$castingcity', '$forename', '$lastname', '$geschlecht', '$picture')";
        if ($datenbank->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            $output = $output . "\n" . "Datenbank Werte eingetragen!";
        } else {
            $output = $output . "\n" . "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $datenbank->error;
        }
    }
}else {
    $output = $output . "\n" . "POST Variable leer!";
}

$datenbank->close();

echo $output;
```

?>

Comment: Blob urls are only available to the browser that created it so you can't access it on the server. You might want to look into uploading files with AJAX and handling file uploads with PHP

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the answer!

Comment: And how can I give the file to the php with javascript after form validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finally solved

If ound this [Tutorial](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax), and it works!!!